# dplyr: Build set of items in list column

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want a column that tracks which items are included in a set based on a predicate. It seems like I should be able to do this with some combination of the purrr `accumulate` function and the dplyr `lead/lag` and `union/setdiff` functions.

This is probably best expressed as a reprex:

```r
input_df <- dplyr::data_frame(user = c("1", "1", "1", "1"),
                              item = c("a", "b", "a", "a"),
                              include = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

output_df <- dplyr::data_frame(user = c("1", "1", "1", "1"),
                               set = list(
                                 c("a"),
                                 c("a", "b"),
                                 c("b"),
                                 c("a", "b")))
```

Edit: I'm very close. I need to find a way of finding the "bag difference" (instead of the set difference) between vectors in case a user includes, excludes and then re-includes an item.

```r
numbered_input_df <- input_df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) 

include_df <- numbered_input_df %>% 
  filter(include == TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(include_set = purrr::accumulate(item, c)) %>% 
  select(user, id, include_set)

exclude_df <- numbered_input_df %>% 
  filter(include == FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(exclude_set = purrr::accumulate(item, c)) %>% 
  select(user, id, exclude_set)

numbered_input_df %>% 
  left_join(include_df) %>% 
  left_join(exclude_df) %>% 
  fill(include_set, exclude_set) %>% 
  mutate(set = map2(include_set, exclude_set, ~.x[! .x %in% .y]))
```

Comment: So you can get the simple result like `purrr::accumulate(input_df$item, c)` - equivalent to `Reduce(c, input_df$item, accumulate=TRUE)` - but what is the rule for your grouping on the basis of `include`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. I would be grouping on the user, and the rows are sorted so that the next row immediately precedes the previous.

Comment: Since this has each row of the output being contingent on the previous row of output, I'm not sure it's doable in a vectorised fashion. Happy to be proven wrong but you could write a `for()` loop to do this a lot simpler probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `Update` which takes the union or setdiff of the basket with the ith item and use Reduce to apply it to each i.  Use `ave` to do all that by user.  No packages are used.

```
Update <- function(basket, i) with(input_df[i, ],
      (if (include) union else setdiff)(basket, item)
)

n <- nrow(input_df)
reduce_user <- function(ix) Reduce(Update, init = NULL, ix, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]

transform(input_df["user"], set = I(ave(as.list(1:n), user, FUN = reduce_user)))
```

giving:

```
  user  set
1    1    a
2    1 a, b
3    1    b
4    1 b, a
```

Alternately, translating the above to dplyr and purrr and making use of `Update` from above we get the code below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

input_df %>%
  mutate(ix = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(set = accumulate(ix, Update, .init = NULL)[-1]) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(user, set)
```

(Note that the only use of purrr is `accumulate` and that could easily be replaced with `Reduce` if you want to reduce dependencies.)